# Ov-chipkaart for non-eu student with Dutch partner

Tags: netherlands, eu-spouses

I, a non-eu student, going to study in the Netherlands the next year. I want to live with my Dutch boyfriend with whom we are going to register partnership in several months.

I would like to move in, but his place is far away from my university, so it's quite expensive with a usual ov-chipkaart. At the same time, in the Netherlands there is a special ov-chipcaart for students which offers a good discount.

Can I, as a partner of eu citizen, apply for it? We were looking for this information with my boyfriend, but couldn't find a clear explanation.

Looking forward to your advice.

Comment: IIANM, the OV-chipkaart itself is just a personal card. The question is whether you can get a periodic student discount of some kind associated with your card, not some special separate card.

Answer (score 4):

The organisation which handles this is [DUO (Dienst Uitvoering Onderwijs)](https://www.duo.nl/), they arrange the student grants. The help for travelling is called the [travel product (reisproduct)](http://www.studentenreisproduct.nl/), and to be able to get this [you have to](https://www.duo.nl/particulier/international-student/student-travel-product/collecting-your-student-travel-product.jsp):

> 1. [First apply for student finance.](https://www.duo.nl/particulier/international-student/student-finance/applying-for-student-finance.jsp)
> 2. Buy a personal OV-chipkaart.
> 3. Register your OV-chipkaart number.
> 4. Load the student travel product onto your OV-chipkaart.

To [apply for finance](https://www.duo.nl/particulier/international-student/student-finance/applying-for-student-finance.jsp) you have to [meet the nationality requirements](https://www.duo.nl/particulier/international-student/student-finance/how-does-it-work.jsp):

> If you are not a national of an EU/EEA-country or Switzerland, you can still qualify for student finance if you have a residence permit type II, III or IV. Check the nationality chart below if you have another type of permit.

You can check if you are entitled [here](https://tools.duo.nl/studiepunt/nationaliteitenschema/natschema.asp?taal=en).

Comment: TL;DR: If you aren't eligible for student finance you aren't eligible for the card. This is the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Anna, the first search giving me next links:

- https://www.ov-chipkaart.nl/apply-1/students.htm
- http://www.studentenreisproduct.nl/detail/ov-chipkaartnummer-doorgeven/
- https://services.studentenreisproduct.nl/koppel/checklist

Based on It I assume you're eligible to have student ov-card.